# Using '$get.JSON()' and ipinfo.io, how do I store the country of origin in a variable

Tags: javascript, json

I'm using `$get.JSON()` and ipinfo.io to retrieve the users country of origin, but somehow I'm not able to store this into a variable. When I try in the following way, the variable contains an object.

```
var loc = $.getJSON("http://ipinfo.io/?callback=?", function(response) {
    return response.country;
});
console.log(loc);
```

This logs a somewhat nonsensical object, looping over the contents of the object doesn't result in anything meaningful (to me anyway).

The following:

```
$.getJSON("http://ipinfo.io/?callback=?", function(response) {
     console.log(respose.country);
     window.locationGlobal = respose.country;
});
console.log(locationGlobal)
```

results in one correct log, the first one, and a reference error on `locationGlobal` (`is not defined`). Which I find baffling because when I call the variable in the JS console I get the expected result.

Is there anyone who can enlighten me? I am in (dire) need of enlightenment here. There has to be something that I'm overlooking but I'm not able to see it. Thanks!

**update:** So I guess I was trying to assign the result of the callback to a global before it was retrieved. If I called the global after the page was loaded with a button on the page the correct answer was retrieved.
I wanted to change text on the page depending on the location of the visitor. I was only was taking two location in consideration. My solution could use some refactoring (on multiple fronts) but at the moment I have something of a "If it aint broken don't try an fix it" attitude...[link](http://millar-knorr.nl/test/suikerwater.html)

Comment: To include inline code, use the button next to 1 on your keyboard, a "backtick", not single quotes.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, I knew but overlooked that part.